# JS сложные селекторы( .parent . child. .child-of-child ...)

Tags: javascript, css-selectors

Есть следующая структура:

```html
<div class='parent' id='parent-1'>
  <div class='blank'>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <ul>
      <li>a</li>
      <li>b</li>
      <li>c</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Нужно с помощью js селекторов вставить текст(из буфера) в тег `<p>` / 
`<li>`.

Comment: Что и куда конкретно вам необходимо вставить?

Answer (score 1):

Можете воспользоваться методом DOM - [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

```js
function change(el) {
  document.querySelector('.parent p:nth-child(2)').innerText = el.value;
  document.querySelector('.parent li:nth-child(3)').innerText = el.value;

}
```

```html
<div class='parent' id='parent-1'>
  <div class='blank'>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <ul>
      <li>a</li>
      <li>b</li>
      <li>c</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<hr/>

<input onkeyup="change(this)" placeholder="Введите значение" />
```